# Restricting Xen dom0 to resuming a saved VM state

Tags: xen

Is anyone aware of a way to restrict usage of dom0 (i.e., the `xm` command) to a certain subset of commands? In my case I'd like to prevent the dom0 user from doing anything other than resuming a saved domU.

I'm guessing that since you need to be root to use the `xm` tool there's not much I can do to restrict powers. I'd love to hear any ideas on other ways of achieving my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying xend to not support certain operations, you can't stop someone with access to the dom0 from starting new domUs, because someone who wanted to start a new domU could just issue API commands.  Honestly, restricting xm commands is somewhat dangerous because there are ways that a domU can crash, and need to be restarted.

Also, if someone who can't be trusted not to start VMs at inappropriate moments has root on your dom0s, I really think your permissions priorities are drunkenly insane.  Instead, consider restricting users who need to do these limited operations to a non-root user, and a sudo-enabled wrapper script provided to manipulate VM state in approved ways.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know sudo-wrapped scripts existed and now I do.